# False Activity opens by clicking on an Item on the Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation, navigation-drawer

I programm a quiz app.There I have also a navigation drawer with the items: Home,stats and about. The first Activity/main activity (quizActivity) has the home item, the second Activity (menu2) has the stats item. Menu3 has the about item. Now I already set up that in Menu2 on the navigation drawer by clicking on the item **home** --> QuizActivity opens. Now I want also, when I click on the about button, that Menu3 will open. But instead of Menu3, my recent app that i used before open itself/it opens the recent page of the app like the Quiz Activity. What is my fault? I checked also other similar threads and could not find help.

Menu2 Java:

```
       public class Menu2 extends AppCompatActivity {




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout2;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Button popup;
private Button popup2;
private Button popup3;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;private LayoutInflater layoutInflater; //Alows to add a new layout in our window



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu2);



    TextView txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore2);
    TextView txtHighScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
    ImageView imgTrophyView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy1);
    ImageView imgTrophyView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trophy2);
    Button bttPOPUP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);
    Button bttPOPUP2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP2);
    Button bttPOPUP3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP3);
    ImageView imgTrophyView3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.trophy3);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int mScore = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
    txtScore.setText("Your score is: " + mScore);



    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);
    if (highScore >= mScore){
        txtHighScore.setText("High score: " + highScore);




        if (highScore >= 10) {
            imgTrophyView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttPOPUP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        if (highScore >= 20) {
            imgTrophyView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttPOPUP2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        if (highScore >= 30) {
            imgTrophyView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bttPOPUP3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }



    }



    else {
        txtHighScore.setText("New highscore: " + mScore);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.commit();
    }



    //Start POPUP window 1

    popup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP);
    popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_1,null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.3);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                    return true;

                }

            });


            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });
        }
    });

    //End POPUP window 1
    //start POPUP window 2

    popup2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP2);
    popup2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_2,null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.3);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                    return true;

                }

            });


            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });
        }
    });

//End POPUP window 2
    //start POPUP window 3

    popup3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enablePOPUP3);
    popup3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_menu2_3,null);
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container,1000,980,true); //400,400=popUp size, true = makes that we can close the pop up by simply click out of the window
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(mDrawerLayout2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 0.3);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

                @Override

                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent  ){
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                    return true;

                }

            });


            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    mDrawerLayout2.setAlpha((float) 1);
                    popupWindow.dismiss();

                }
            });
        }
    });

    //End POPUP window 3



    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout2 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout2);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout2, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout2.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv2);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            Intent i;


            if (id == R.id.nav_home2) {
                // Handle the home action
                i = new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_about2) {
                i = new Intent(Menu2.this, Menu3.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            return true;
        }

        });
    }









@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);




}
```

}

Navigation menu:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:id="@+id/nav_home2"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_black_24dp"/>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_stats2"
    android:title="Stats"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:checked="true"/>

<item android:id="@+id/nav_about2"
    android:title="About"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"/>

</menu>
```

Menu 2 XML:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu2"
          android:id="@+id/drawerLayout2"
          android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        layout="@layout/navigation_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f60"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="Your score is:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FFAB00"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Highest score:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textScore2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Restart Quiz!"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:text="Stats: play and get trophies!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />





        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/statsTrophy"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/statsoftrophy"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textHighScore"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tryAgain_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/trophy1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="Info"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trophy2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/trophy2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/statsTrophy"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/statsTrophy"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy3"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enablePOPUP3"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pill_trophy"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:alpha="0.30"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enablePOPUP2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/trophy3"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/trophy3" />


    </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu2"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Menu3 Java:

```
        public class Menu3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout3;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu3);


    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawerLayout3 = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout3, R.string.open, 
    R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout3.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(nv3);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case(R.id.nav_home3):
                    Intent accountActivity3 = new 
         Intent(getApplicationContext(),QuizActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity3);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });}

public void onClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Menu3.this, QuizActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}




@Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

 }
```

Menu3 XML:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="amapps.impossiblequiz.Menu3"
      android:id="@+id/drawerLayout3">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu3"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv3"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tint_color_selector2">




</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Add the menu3 activity here to check if dont have any problem thanks.

Comment: I added the menu3 activity sir

Comment: like I said you have to have the same code in 3 places, check your onNavigationItemSelected method. but this is bad practice, you should follow the tutorial that I gave you if you wanna do this properly

Comment: I do not want to do it with fragments right now... First of all I want to try to solve it with my code and @BrunoFerreira  is helping me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change the **onNavigationItemSelected()** to:

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

             switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
                 case R.id.nav_home2:
                 startActivity(new Intent(Menu2.this, QuizActivity.class));
                 break;
                 case R.id.nav_about2:
                 startActivity(new Intent(Menu2.this, Menu3.class));
                 break;
             }

                return true;
     }
```

Comment: Hello I will definitely try THIS answer , tomorror... If it works i vote you up sir!

Comment: everytime an item is clicked the intent value is changed. So how should this change anything?

Comment: So probably the intent value in the second time that he clicks in navigation item not changes, using the switch case avoids that by not changing intent value but instead launch a new intent I interpreted like that @Nenco and switch case is a better way to do that, because is nore efficiently.

Comment: I agree that a switch is better way, but it still wont change a thing mate :)

Comment: I asked to put the menu3 activity to see if it have some problem, after that if I found some other problem I will update my answer. I want help he turns the app better and fix the problem :) @Nenco

Comment: Thank you i will try it tomorrow after work!:) @Bruno Ferreira

Comment: well its obvious that he has a problem in other activities because it depends from which activity he goes, so he has to have the same code in 3 activites which is just bad practices, also an approach with fragments is a lot better. I haven't seen anyone yet doing this with activities but the thing is that he probably doesn't know how to work with fragments, so he choose the easy way out which ends up worse in this case.

Comment: if you are trying things that means that you dont understand it. try to understand the code don't just run the app to see what happens :)

Comment: @Nenco I agree with you but he asked that have problem when change activity so I will fix that if he want to turn the app better using fragments he only needs to search in Google, I answer wat he asked :)

Comment: you think that you are helping him by giving him the easy way out when you are actually not. Let's say that he makes an app an uses it as a portfolio for a job that he likes. Every developer there will tell him that this is not how its done. And its not in our interest to put him down but to tell him what is right :)

Comment: Yes I know that probably is not the best way but I ask to try helping, and you says that he can do using a better way, for me its fine to have people like you showing a better way than mine, because me and he learn a better way to do. I'm happy to have other people opinion, and happy to learn a little more @Nenco :)

Comment: @BrunoFerreira nothing changed... By clicking in the menu the item about, the app force closes...

Comment: The error in the logcat is: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: The only thing that in Menu3 the "Burger Icon" is now missing!!

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); without this line all is working fine but the Navigation burger item isn`t shoing up... How can I insert it and avoi the Java Nullpointer?

Comment: you are using a toolbar, so probably is your styles you are using a noActionBar style in menu3 Activity?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you have 3 activities and it depends from which activity you go to which. So you'll have to have the same code in multiple places regarding the item that you clicked.

A lot better way to do this is with fragments.

You should check this tutorial:
https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Also check the MVP design pattern.